# Can't set height percentage to table on CodePen with HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

Just started FreeCodeCamp 4 weeks ago and this is my very first post, sorry if I sound stupid, please don't yell at me. I tried to research why I'm failing at this. I'm trying to set table height to 40%.

It works fine when I set it in px, and the width works fine as well. But the height percent doesn't. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Relevant bits of code:

```
<style>
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
height: 100%;
background-color: #113
}
table {
width:70%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="pics" id="pic1">Picture1</td>
<td class="pics" id="pic2">Picture2</td>
<td class="pics" id="pic3">Picture3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="desc" id="desc1">Decs1</td>
<td class="desc" id="desc2">Decs2</td>
<td class="desc" id="desc3">Decs13</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Whole code:http://codepen.io/RadaCodes/pen/YqXjWj?editors=1000